# import httplib ImportError: No module named httplib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this error when run test.py

```
C:\Python32>python.exe test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import httplib
ImportError: No module named httplib
```

How to correct it?

Code block for **test.py**:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import httplib
import sys
import re
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


class miniHTMLParser( HTMLParser ):

  viewedQueue = []
  instQueue = []

  def get_next_link( self ):
    if self.instQueue == []:
      return ''
    else:
      return self.instQueue.pop(0)


  def gethtmlfile( self, site, page ):
    try:
      httpconn = httplib.HTTPConnection(site)
      httpconn.request("GET", page)
      resp = httpconn.getresponse()
      resppage = resp.read()
    except:
      resppage = ""

    return resppage


  def handle_starttag( self, tag, attrs ):
    if tag == 'a':
      newstr = str(attrs[0][1])
      if re.search('http', newstr) == None:
        if re.search('mailto', newstr) == None:
          if re.search('htm', newstr) != None:
            if (newstr in self.viewedQueue) == False:
              print ("  adding", newstr)
              self.instQueue.append( newstr )
              self.viewedQueue.append( newstr )
          else:
            print ("  ignoring", newstr)
        else:
          print ("  ignoring", newstr)
      else:
        print ("  ignoring", newstr)


def main():

  if sys.argv[1] == '':
    print ("usage is ./minispider.py site link")
    sys.exit(2)

  mySpider = miniHTMLParser()

  link = sys.argv[2]

  while link != '':

    print ("\nChecking link ", link)

    # Get the file from the site and link
    retfile = mySpider.gethtmlfile( sys.argv[1], link )

    # Feed the file into the HTML parser
    mySpider.feed(retfile)

    # Search the retfile here

    # Get the next link in level traversal order
    link = mySpider.get_next_link()

  mySpider.close()

  print ("\ndone\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You are running Python 2 code on Python 3. In Python 3, the module has been renamed to [`http.client`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html).

You could try to run the [`2to3` tool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#to3-reference) on your code, and try to have it translated automatically. References to `httplib` will automatically be rewritten to use `http.client` instead.

Comment: why do i get this error when pip install http.client? `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement http.client (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for http.client
`

Comment: @LeiYang you can’t install the library, it is part of the standard library of Python 3. If you are using Python 2 and get an import error for `http.client` you need to use Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 16):

you can just import http.client and rename it to httplib with this code :

import http.client as httplib

Comment: This is the best answer! Very neat

Answer (score -1):

If you use PyCharm, please change you 'Project Interpreter' to '2.7.x'

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue when I was trying to make my Docker container smaller.  It was because I'd installed Python 2.7 with:

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python
```

And I should not have included the `--no-install-recommends` flag:

```
apt-get install -y python
```