# ImportError: No module named 'httplib' selenium python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

This code was working without any problem and after I installed scrapy lib I get this error. I don't know if there is any relation between them and how to fix it.
this's my full traceback

> > Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 2195, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> >     AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**path**'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line
>   23, in 
>       import http.client as http_client   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 69, in 
>       import email.parser   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/parser.py", line 12, in 
>       from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in 
>       from email import message   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 15, in 
>       from email import utils   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/utils.py", line 31, in 
>       import urllib.parse ImportError: No module named 'urllib.parse'; 'urllib' is not a package
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "adder.py", line 2, in
>   
>       from selenium import webdriver   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/**init**.py", line
>   18, in 
>       from selenium import selenium   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/selenium.py", line
>   25, in 
>       import httplib as http_client ImportError: No module named 'httplib'

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0

usr = ('*****')
pwd = ('*****')

url = 'http://www.example.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# or you can use Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("login_username")
elem.send_keys(usr)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("login_password")
elem.send_keys(pwd)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(20)

File = open('/home/shar/test11','r');
for line in File.readlines():
  try:
    driver.get(line)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('example').click()
    time.sleep(15)
  except:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import httplib ImportError: No module named httplib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778252/import-httplib-importerror-no-module-named-httplib)

Comment: can you provide full traceback log?

Comment: i added it to question @Andersson

Comment: @MohamedElsharkawey, This error occurs both on `Python2` and `Python3`?

Comment: python3 but that was't happend before