# Can't install Psychopy module on python 3 (Mac)

Tags: python-3.x, installation, psychopy

I’m trying to install psychopy on Python 3 on a Mac but I get an error:

```
pip3 install psychopy

Collecting psychopy

Using cached PsychoPy-1.84.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in 
File “/private/var/folders/39/88clnp910zlg54lrgy0d7qm40000gn/T/pip-build-ddca2hwz/psychopy/setup.py”, line 28, in 
exec(vStr)
File “”, line 42, in 
File “/private/var/folders/39/88clnp910zlg54lrgy0d7qm40000gn/T/pip-build-ddca2hwz/psychopy/psychopy/init.py”, line 47, in 
from psychopy.tools.versionchooser import useVersion, ensureMinimal
File “/private/var/folders/39/88clnp910zlg54lrgy0d7qm40000gn/T/pip-build-ddca2hwz/psychopy/psychopy/tools/versionchooser.py”, line 19, in 
from psychopy import logging, tools, web
File “/private/var/folders/39/88clnp910zlg54lrgy0d7qm40000gn/T/pip-build-ddca2hwz/psychopy/psychopy/web.py”, line 13, in 
import httplib
ImportError: No module named ‘httplib’

----------------------------------------
Command “python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/39/88clnp910zlg54lrgy0d7qm40000gn/T/pip-build-ddca2hwz/psychopy/
```

I tried to install “httplib” but no luck there also:

```
pip3 install httplib

Collecting httplib

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httplib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for httplib
```

How should I install it?

Answer (score 1):

The error in importing `httplib` is caused by [using Python 2 code with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778252/import-httplib-importerror-no-module-named-httplib). [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) is a built-in library provided by Python 2.x – it cannot be installed with Pip, and has been renamed to `http.client` in Python 3.

After checking the [installation instructions](http://psychopy.org/installation.html), it appears that Python 3 is **not supported** as of version 1.85.4:

> #### Dependencies
>
> You need a copy of Python 2.7.x from here, wxPython and probably pyo (or use an alternative audio library listed below).

You will need to install and use Python 2.7 instead, unfortunately, as Python 3 will not work, and you'll likely experience many Python 3 bugs even if you did fix the direct issue with `httplib` yourself.

Comment: Python3 support will arrive in 1.86.00 but this is a major refactor, so bugs are likely in the first few 1.86.x releases.

Comment: @Aurora0001 No way around it? I must use python3 for other packeges (e.g. nltk). Any proper replacement for psychopy?

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Do you have an idea how long it should take?

Comment: Not exactly, but my impression is that it could be within a month from now. I think that one of the backends of OpenSesame supports python3, but I'm not sure: http://osdoc.cogsci.nl/3.1/important-changes-3/#support-for-python-3

Answer (score 0):

Oren has duplicated the question on the PsychoPy forum and I answered it there:
https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/cant-install-psychopy-in-python3-mac/3573/5

The repository version of PsychoPy is now compatible but, as Jonas says, it was a major refactor (needed an upgrade to wx4 from wx3 as well) and is likely to have bugs. Not recommended unless you know what you're doing.