# How to fix Psycopg2 Error Pip Installation in Mac Terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm trying to install Psycopg2 in my Mac terminal. I have tried to install according the guide here http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html

But I'm still getting this long error:

```
pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/d7/6a93c99b5ba4d4d22daa3928b983cec66df4536ca50b22ce5dcac65e4e71/psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-install-2q6kbmci/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-install-2q6kbmci/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-record-0s50efj1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-install-2q6kbmci/psycopg2/
    Complete output (144 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o
    psycopg/pqpath.c:135:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(*pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1714:11: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
        ret = 1;
              ^
    psycopg/pqpath.c:1819:17: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'ConnStatusType' to different enumeration type 'ExecStatusType' [-Wenum-conversion]
                    PQstatus(curs->conn->pgconn) : PQresultStatus(curs->pgres)));
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    3 warnings generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o
    In file included from psycopg/bytes_format.c:81:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/libpq_support.c:29:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/win32_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/win32_support.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/solaris_support.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o
    In file included from psycopg/solaris_support.c:28:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/column_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_connection_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_connection_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_cursor_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/replication_message_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/replication_message_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/diagnostics_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/error_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/conninfo_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o
    In file included from psycopg/notify_type.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/xid_type.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o
    In file included from psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c:27:
    In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:37:
    ./psycopg/config.h:81:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
    static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
                ^
    1 warning generated.
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64) -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120001 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/postgresql/server -c psycopg/typecast.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/xid_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg/typecast.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-install-2q6kbmci/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-install-2q6kbmci/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zn/9cblm4hj0sb_69k14cc1j31r0000gp/T/pip-record-0s50efj1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: Try to install the binary package: `pip install psycopg2-binary`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Psychopy module on python 3 (MAC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846734/cant-install-psychopy-module-on-python-3-mac)

Comment: The error is at the end of that looong error message: "*ld: library not found for -lssl*". You need to install openssl. See the solutions at [error installing psycopg2, library not found for -lssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288042/error-installing-psycopg2-library-not-found-for-lssl).