# Flask cannot run and stop during initialization

Tags: python, flask

I'm not able to run flask successfully

When i execute the apps_server.py..it stop initialized as follow

> Serving Flask app "apps_server" (lazy loading)  Environment:production
>   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
>   Use a production WSGI server instead.
>   Debug mode: on

It just stuck at that point...and there is no Running on http://localhost:5000/ line show up...

May I know what could be the problem?

This is snippet of the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Markup, request, jsonify
from flask.helpers import send_file
import os,httplib,json,subprocess
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify, abort, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
import argparse, sys
import logging
import logging.config
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import Formatter


#app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@@Functions and code to execute@@

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.debug = True
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Please advise further.

Comment: Can you please try http://0.0.0.0:5000, secondly what does this line means? `@@Functions and code to execute@@`

Comment: What `@@Functions and code to execute@@`  does ?

Comment: Try to replace these `app.debug = True` `app.config["DEBUG"] = True` by  `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5000)`

Comment: (1)It doesn't work...as the server is not running....(2)@@Functions and code to execute@@ --this is nothing...just to tell that a lines of code...

Comment: @Antoine F ... still the same behavior...server not run stop at Debug mode: on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your code working by doing the following changes:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Markup, request, jsonify
from flask.helpers import send_file
import os,http.client,json,subprocess
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify, abort, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
import argparse, sys
import logging
import logging.config
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import Formatter

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Try now ;) Seems like it might have been the debugging. Also, make sure that the `@app.route` statement is correct. If you are using a template here and there is just a small mistake, it will not work. I am not sure if your code is correct inside what you call the `@@Functions and code to execute@@`. Make sure that whatever you have inside here is correct. Python 3 also renamed httplib to http.client (ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778252/import-httplib-importerror-no-module-named-httplib)), so I changed this during the import. However, the code above is working for me.

Also, if you want to use a template (as you've indicated in the post), you can refer to the template as following:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

Remember to make a directory called "templates", and put the home.html file there. Flask will automatically look for the "templates" directory.

Comment: Thank you ErikDM. ...so... need remove app=Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

Comment: No problem mate. I've edited the post and added how to route to your template.