# python3 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, http, module

i'm trying to run the script in a python3 windows environment.  i've attempted to reinstall the httplib2 library and that doesn't seem to help.

```
from httplib2 import httplib2
http = httplib2.Http()
content = http.request("http://mit.edu")[1]
```

and i'm getting the error

> uri = httplib2.iri2uri(uri) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

I hope  this is something simple i am overlooking.  thanks in advance

> (mp4) C:\temp\ffmpeg\MP4\dev>python Python 3.7.4
> (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
> (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
> more information.
> >>>import httplib2
> >>> httplib2.iri2uri() Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  TypeError: 'module' object is not
> callable
> >>> quit()
>
> ```
>     (mp4) C:\temp\ffmpeg\MP4\dev>pip install httplib2 Requirement already satisfied: httplib2 in
>  c:\temp\ffmpeg\mp4\dev\mp4\lib\site-packages (0.20.4) Requirement
>  already satisfied: pyparsing!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,!=3.0.2,!=3.0.3,<4,>=2.4
>  .2 in c:\temp\ffmpeg\mp4\dev\mp4\lib\site-packages (from httplib2)
>  (3.0.9)
>
>         
>         (mp4) C:\temp\ffmpeg\MP4\dev>python Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit
> ```
>
> (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
> more information.
> >>> from httplib2 import httplib2
> >>> http = httplib2.Http()
> >>> content = http.request("http://mit.edu")[1] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
> "C:\temp\ffmpeg\MP4\dev\httplib2_*init*_.py", line 1426, in request
> uri = httplib2.iri2uri(uri) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

it might be due to using a **python2 library for python3**. I am pretty sure that httplib2 only works with python2. I will attach a relevant discussion that will help you resolve the issue. [import httplib ImportError: No module named httplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778252/import-httplib-importerror-no-module-named-httplib)