Is it possible to create a to create a localhost html file with a Python http module?
So I was trying to make localhost with http.server. I used some help from the docs, but I got an error. I tried to fix it, but I was still unable to fix it.
Here is the code:
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
loop = True
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('result.html', 5050)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
    if loop == True:
        httpd.server_close()




while loop:
    run()
    ex = input("To close the server write 'exit' /n <<< ")
    if ex.find(f'exit'):
        loop = False

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\localhost\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    run()
  File "E:\Python\localhost\main.py", line 5, in run
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socketserver.py", line 457, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\http\server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\socketserver.py", line 473, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Process finished with exit code 1


maybe this thread will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778252/import-httplib-importerror-no-module-named-httplib

The name of the file does not go into the server address.

server_address should have IP address like 127.0.0.1, not file name. ('127.0.0.1', 5050). But if you want to serve HTML files then it is simpler to run python -m http.server and it will server all files in current folder.

there is other problem: serve_forever() is running all time and it blocks next lines. It will not allow to run input() and while-loop. You will need to use Ctrl+C to stop it.

other problem: BaseHTTPRequestHandler is useless as handler. You have to use it to create own handler class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler) and add method do_GET() which will read file result.html and send its content to web browser.

You have many mistakes in your code. It also shows that you don't know how work (web) servers.
But better I will show how to use http in the simplest way.
If you want to serve files in current folder then the simplest method is to run in system console (terminal/bash/powershell/etc.)
python3 -m http.server 5050

and it will run built-in function which will run simple web server.
It will show in console
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 5050 (http://0.0.0.0:5050/) ...

and you can copy address http://0.0.0.0:5050/ to web browser to connect to this server.
In some consoles you may even click text with address and system may open it in web browser
(some terminals may need to press key Ctrl when you click)
If you would have file index.html in current folder then it would show you this file.
If you don't have index.html then it will show you list of all files and subfolders in current folders and you may click result.html to display it. If you click folder then it should show files in this folder but if this folder has file index.html then it will display this index.html
So sometimes using name index.html can make it all simpler.
And it can hide files which you have in folder.

If you want to serve files from other folder then use
python3 -m http.server 5050 -d /path/to/other/directory


If you still want to write code then you have mistakes:

server_address has to use IP address (like 127.0.0.1) or domain name (like localhost) without path with filename and/or folder names because this information is processed in handler.

BaseHTTPRequestHandler can't be used directly because it doesn't have function do_GET() (and eventually do_POST()). You have to use this class to create own handler and add function do_GET()
 class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler): 
      def do_GET(self): 
          ...

It will run this function for every path in URL like /result.html and you get it in self.path - and you have to decide what to do with this path

serve_forever() runs forever and it blocks next lines - so using input() and while-loop is useless. You have to use keys Ctrl+C to stop server.


Full working example:
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import os

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print('path:', self.path)
        
        if os.path.exists('result.html'):
            with open('result.html', 'rb') as f:  # bytes, not string
                data = f.read()
                
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(data,)

        else:
            data = b"Not found: result.html"   # bytes, not string
            
            self.send_response(404)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(data,)
            
        return
        
#server_address = ('localhost', 5050)  # access only from current computer
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 5050)  # access only from current computer
#server_address = ('0.0.0.0', 5050)  # access from all computers in local network (if firewall doesn't stop it)

httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)

print(f"Running http://{server_address[0]}:{server_address[1]}")
print("Press Ctrl+C to stop it")

try:
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\rStopping")    # `\r` to remove `^C` from screen`

